# How can I take the #text part of the website with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The website has this in the inspect code:

```html
<a href="https://eltlearningjourneys.com/2015/05/12/5-different-english-classes/" rel="prev">
  <span class="meta-nav">←</span> 
  Previous
</a>
```

The "Previous" is a #text. I'm scraping with beautifulsoup
but I can't get the text "Previous".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk

html = """
<a href="https://eltlearningjourneys.com/2015/05/12/5-different-      english-classes/" rel="prev">
    <span class="meta-nav">←</span> 
    Previous
</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Define a list of CSS selectors for the visible elements in the HTML
visible_selectors = ['p', 'span', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'li', 'td', 'th', 'label', 'button', 'a', 'small', 'strong', 'em', 'blockquote', 'div[role="article"]', '#text']

# Find all elements that match the CSS selectors and contain visible text
elements = []

for selector in visible_selectors:
    elements += soup.select(selector + ':not([class*="hidden"]):not([style*="display:none"])')

for element in elements:
    # Get the visible text within the element
    visible_text = ' '.join(element.text.split())
    
    # Split the visible text into sentences
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(visible_text)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if sentence == "" or sentence == None:
            continue
        else:
            print(sentence)
```

In the picture below, I was only able to get the bold text because it's in the 'strong'. I want to get the other texts too. If I can get the full text together (before the strong, strong and after the strong together as a sentence) that would be better.

[image]

Comment: Looks like I copied it incorrectly to here, now the code should be fine in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply using [`.get_Text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://eltlearningjourneys.com/2015/05/19/websites-for-learning-english/').text)

soup.body.get_text(' ',strip=True)
```

###### Output

```
Skip to primary content ELT Learning Journeys Blog Pearson ELT Spain and Portugal Search Main menu Home Our teacher trainers and collaborators Categories Ideas for Class English language Places we have been Pearson Teaching Teens Travel Tools Workshops Culture Post navigation ← Previous Next → 10 great websites for learning English Posted on May 19, 2015 by Daniel Vincent With such an abundance of authentic English online these days, from videos to articles, podcasts to blogs, there’s no excuse not to use the internet to help you improve. However, you might also want something targeted especially at the learner. Here, alphabetically, are 10 great websites for learning English that we think you’ll enjoy. Great websites for learning English you should know 1. Amigos Ingleses Aimed at Spanish speakers, this website has resources for practicing listening skills and conversational English, including a Youtube channel with lots of fun videos to help you master the trickier aspects of English pronunciation. 2. BBC Learning English The BBC website for learning English has lots of free resources, including courses at different levels, an online drama to follow, vocabulary, grammar and listening practice, words in the news and graded articles on all sorts of interesting topics. There are sections for kids, teens and adults. 3. British Council Learn English Here you can find free video and audio resources for learners of all ages and at all levels, including games, English skills through football, a mini soap opera, podcasts, articles and a discussion forum to ask questions, find advice about learning English and make friends from all over the world. 4. Duolingo A great website for learning vocabulary and grammar through interactive games and quizzes. There is an emphasis on pronunciation as you have to repeat back words and complete each lesson correctly before moving on to the next. It also lets you set your own goals and monitor your progress. 5. Flo-joe If you’re planning to take the Cambridge First, Advanced or Proficiency exam or the\xa0IELTS exam and you’re looking for some extra practice, this site has lots of exam-task practice for each of the papers. Make sure you time yourself in order to get used to exam conditions and keep notes of what you learn. 6. Live Mocha This website pairs you up with someone trying to learn your language so that you can have an online exchange with a real native speaker and become part of a global community of language learners. Everyone helps out with comments, corrections, tips and encouragement. You also have access to English lessons and various resources for listening and reading practice. 7. Lyrics training Songs are a great way to practice both listening and – if you sing along – pronunciation. This fun website lets you test your skills by typing in missing words as the song of your choice plays section by section. You can challenge yourself from easy to hard. 8. News in Levels If you follow the news, why not follow it in English? This site has loads of current news stories, plus an extensive archive, all divided into three levels so that you can catch up on what’s happening in the world no matter what your level of English is. 9. Talk English This is a great site for learning English, with lots of free listening practice with accompanying exercises as well as lessons in general English, business English, English for interviews and English for travel. 10. TED Here you can find hundreds of fascinating short lectures by experts in everything from design to psychology. Although not strictly a website for learning English, it is very accessible to non-native speakers. Subtitles are available in English for every talk; unlike subtitles for movies and TV shows, which are abbreviated versions of the actual dialogue, TED subtitles are complete, meaning they’re great for listening practice. A transcript is also available. More info: ELT Argentina – ELT Chile – ELT Spain & Portugal – ELT Uruguay & Paraguay Get our best posts directly in your inbox SUBSCRIBE TO OUR BLOG! Sign up now Share this: Tweet Related This entry was posted in English language , Onine resources and tagged Cambridge Exams , exams , Listening , Online resoruces , self study , Videos , Vocabulary by Daniel Vincent . Bookmark the permalink . 3 thoughts on “ 10 great websites for learning English ” Pingback: 10 great sites with free games for practising English Pingback: 10 ways to improve your English outside of class Pingback: 7 tips for English exam Leave a Reply Cancel reply Proudly powered by WordPress Subscribe to our blog Subscribe Now Your Privacy is protected. x Loading Comments... Write a Comment... Email (Required) Name (Required) Website
```

Comment: Because I'm trying to get texts, translate them and put them back to the htm/html file. With .get_Text() it just translates and put them without no structure.

Comment: Interesting detail that should be addressed in the question to get more specific answers. Perhaps it would be good to [create  a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that focuses on this and other details that are important to get a better idea of what you like to do.